# Google Sheets Apps Script Copy Row of Data If date same as tab name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found some code that almost does what i need and have tried playing around with it to get it to work, but no luck. I get an export with data with dates in the last column on every row.

I simply want to copy the last column rows of dates to the tabs with the same name.

```
function MoveDate_FourthDEC() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Import");
var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("4/12/2020");
var rg1=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow(),32);//starting at column2
var data=rg1.getValues();
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
// 13 = collected should be in this column which is column N
if(data[i][31]=="4/12/2020") {
sh2.appendRow(data[i]);
}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Your goal is to copy all the rows for which column `AF` matches the names of the sheets.
- To begin with, you can use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over every sheet. For each sheet, you want to check whether the sheet name matches a date in column `AF`. If it does, then you need to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) only the rows that contain this date in column `AF` and store them into an temporary array:

  `let temp_data = data.filter(r=>r[31]==sh.getName());`
- Then you can efficiently copy and paste all the relevant rows to the matching sheet:

`sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,temp_data.length,temp_data[0].length).setValues(temp_data);`

---

**Side notes:**

- When dealing with date objects you need to consider the display values in the sheet. This is why I am using [getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead of [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Since `data` starts from the second row, you need to deduct one row from the last row with content, to get the correct range:

  `getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,32)`
- I am using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the sheet name matches the last column. In order to use `includes` you need to [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten the 2D array that is returned by the `getDisplayValues` function.

---

### Solution:

```
function MoveDate_FourthDEC() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Import");
const shs = ss.getSheets();
const dts = sh1.getRange('AF2:AF'+sh1.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
const data=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,32).getDisplayValues();
shs.forEach(sh=>{
if (dts.includes(sh.getName())){
let temp_data = data.filter(r=>r[31]==sh.getName());
sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,temp_data.length,temp_data[0].length).setValues(temp_data);
}});
}
```

Comment: Marios I do appreciate the time it took you to do this. thank you very much